# Connecting to IBM MQ without any IBM dependency jars from java client

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

Is it possible to connect to IBM MQ and read/write a message to queue without using any IBM dependency jar files.  For example , I want to write pure JMS code to connect to IBM MQ , in this case do I still require IBM jars to connect?  I assume we still need IBM client jars? Please validate my understanding.

Basically I want to connect to IBM MQ using java client without any IBM jars. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Basically, that's not possible. But why do you want to do this? If we can understand why there may be a different solution.

Comment: I just want to avoid the dependency of ibm jars.. so if the server upgrades , don't have to upgrade the client jars..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible, as only IBM MQ JMS jars have the knowledge on how to communicate with IBM MQ queue manager and put/get messages. The question is why you don't want to use IBM MQ jars?

JMS is only a specification, not an implementation, just like TCP specifications. The actual implementation of JMS API is provided by vendors, like IBM, Oracle. The JMS API implementation is vendor specific, meaning IBM MQ JMS API implementation will work with IBM MQ only, not with any other JMS provider.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.. So if we update the IBM MQ server , does the client jars also needs to be updated?

Comment: IBM MQ servers and clients are meant to be backwards and forwards compliant.  See [MQ 7.x, MQ 8.0, MQ 9.0 and MQ 9.1 compatibility with previous versions - including usage of CCDT files, JMS .bindings, SSL/TLS](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/mq-7x-mq-80-mq-90-and-mq-91-compatibility-previous-versions-including-usage-ccdt-files-jms-bindings-ssltls). Anything less than v8.0 is out of support and v8.0 goes out of support in April 2020.  Even if you don't have to upgraded the jars,  you should to be at a supported version.

Answer (score 2):

You say "if the server upgrades , I don't want to have to upgrade the client jars".

Well you're in luck. There is zero requirement to have matching client side and server side versions. Pick a version now and just keep using it. You only ever have to upgrade the client jars if you need a feature that was added in a newer version of the jars than you are using.

This any-version-to-any-version client/server protocol has always been a strong point in the IBM MQ implementation.

Comment: Morag, you would not recommend staying at least at a supported version?

Comment: Staying at a supported version is a worthy goal, but it unhelpfully goes against the OP requirement of not having to upgrade the client jars.

Comment: With the relocatable `com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar` it makes updating so much easier than it used to be.   With the number of defects and improvements fixpack over fixpack and version over version no one should want to stay on a unsupported version of the client.

Comment: Agreed @JoshMc :-)